# Getting a pivot column in Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to retrieve some models and a `pivot` column in the same query.

I have 3 tables.

materials

```
id | name
```

items_fabrics

```
id | name | item_id
```

items_fabrics_materials

```
id | fabric_id | material_id | percentage
```

Using `Item::with('fabrics', 'fabrics.materials')->find(1);`

I can get all the fabrics and materials, but the `percentage` column is left out. How do I get this with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `withPivot()` in the model did the trick.

`return $this->belongsToMany('Material', 'items_fabrics_materials')->withPivot('percentage');`